# Can I apply for ESTA with passport valid since february?

Tags: usa, passports, esta

I plan to visit the US so I need to obtain an ESTA but will it be a problem that I have a new passport? I had a passport once when I was like 10 years old and none since then. Won’t they be suspicious at the airport in the US?

Comment: Why would having a new passport be a problem?  Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @phoog, some people hear about the passport valid for 6 months rule and think that this before you can start using it. I do not see why you think this question unclear.

Comment: There are many countries that don't require their citizens to hold a passport when other forms of ID are available. IIRC, the US is one of them. It is the opposite of suspicious to get your first passport when you plan a trip to another continent for the first time in your life (which I assume is the case here).

Comment: Having a new passport cannot be problematic since passports only have a limited validity, at least in most countries. After the passport expires, you get a new one, just like that, and the validity dates will not include the prior passport's issue date but the new ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, not having had a passport is not a problem at the border, nor is a new passport a problem.

When you apply for an ESTA you have to answer all questions truthful and when you meet the requirements you will be granted an ESTA, if you do not meet the requirements you can apply for a visa, in which case they look further into your personal history.

Comment: 5% of the people on the flight with you will also have new passports (meaning issued in the last 6 months) assuming a 10 year passport expiration time.